# RAM & mobo basic compatibility vs actual maximum frequency supported

Tags: memory

I was looking to upgrade RAM because I wanted RGB RAM in my system. However, I couldn't justify the purchase until I saw some benchmarks showing that CPU-intensive games get a surprisingly decent FPS boost from RAM with higher clock speeds--performance boosts of 10-25 FPS (depending on the game) at 1080p when upgrading from 4800mhz to 6400mhz. Obviously, the increase will be smaller at 4k. The point is I feel I can justify the purchase if I get a mild increase in performance, as I don't want to buy the same speed RAM.

The issue is I'm seeing that Corsair vengeance DDR5 7200mmhz RAM is compatible with my mobo on PCpartpicker, but when I check the mobo manufacturer's website, it says, "Supports DDR5 Memory, up to 6400+(OC) MHz." On a different source (pangoly.com), it shows only up to 6400mhz being supported. Does this mean the 7200mhz memory will boot, but I won't achieve those frequencies? Does the "+" imply over 6400mhz is achievable? I'd rather get the fastest RAM I can since I'm upgrading, but if it isn't utilized properly anyway, then I'd just get the 6400mhz.

The mobo is MSI z690-a pro DDR5, and the CPU is 12700k for reference. The current RAM is Corsair Vengeance 5200mhz. Also, possibly worth mentioning that all of this implies I will only be using the XMP profile, not (necessarily) planning on tuning any other OC settings for RAM.

Comment: Depending on what FPS you are getting now, getting 10-25 more FPS is *NOT* worth the investment.  And that is assuming that it accurate for your hardware...

Comment: @Keltari - Apparently, DDR5 performance at higher frequencies, is actually significant so a 20% increase the memory frequency can bring substantial performance increases.

Comment: @Ramhound That may be true, but the value of higher FPS decreases the higher your FPS is.  Obviously, a 20 FPS increase over 20 FPS is massive.  However, 20 FPS if you are getting 200 is negligible.  Thats a lot of money to spend to *possibly* get a few more FPS that you might not even notice.  More isnt always better, especially when more is expensive.

Comment: Although I actually agree with you objectively, it is at the end of the day a subjective argument. My budget is not limited so the point is moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue is I see that Corsair vengeance DDR5 7200mmhz RAM is compatible with my mobo on PCpartpicker, but when I check the mobo manufacturer's website, it says, "Supports DDR5 Memory, up to 6400+(OC) MHz."

I won't begin to understand how that particular website determines compatibility if it's based on data inputted by end consumers. Being compatible and running at the indicated base frequency of the memory module are two entirely different things.  Will you're system boot if you install a maximum of two 7200 Mhz DDR5 modules? Absolutely.  It will, however, downclock those modules to 6400 Mhz.

> Does this mean the 7200mhz memory will boot, but I won't achieve those frequencies?

Yes

> Does the "+" imply over 6400mhz is achievable?

According to the [specifications](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/PRO-Z690-A/support#mem) of the motherboard, the maximum DDR5 frequency support by a 12th generation Intel Core K Series processor is 6600 Mhz.  Whoever was the product description editor likely was lazy or smart, depending on your viewpoint, and stopped attempting to least every iteration of memory frequency supported by the motherboard.